# Can I search all my registers to paste a value

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm restructuring some text including a line that contains the text "log". After a bit more editing, I want to paste the log line, but its now in some far-off register. Is there a way to search all registers for the first that contains the term "log" and paste its contents?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable what on earth are you....are you thinking about the windows registry? That's...not what we're talking bout here at all. Ed - oh wait, I see - joking. Good Troll.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect i'm dyslectic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
function! SearchAndPasteReg()
    let l:pattern = input('Reg search: ')
    if l:pattern == '' | return | endif
    for l:i in range(1, 9)
        if match(eval('@'.l:i), l:pattern) != -1
            execute printf('normal "%i]p', l:i)
            return
        endif
    endfor
    redraw | echo 'Pattern not found'
endf

nnoremap <silent> ]R :call SearchAndPasteReg()<cr>
```

I'm not sure if you are talking about numbered registers, or all the registers. If you want to search for all regs, just extend the range with a list containing all the desired register names, something like this:

```
function! SearchAndPasteReg()
    let l:pattern = input('Reg search: ')
    if l:pattern == '' | return | endif

    let l:regs = range(char2nr('1'), char2nr('9'))
    call map(extend(l:regs, range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z'))), 'nr2char(v:val)')

    for l:reg in l:regs
        if match(eval('@'.l:reg), l:pattern) != -1
            execute printf('normal "%s]p', l:reg)
            return
        endif
    endfor
    redraw | echo 'Pattern not found'
endf

nnoremap <silent> ]R :call SearchAndPasteReg()<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way(not very handy though) would be to redirect output to a register you don't use, lets say z.

```
:redir @z
```

list registries

```
:reg
```

And paste the result from `"z` in some buffer and then is searchable.

And you will also have to stop the redirection after.

```
:redir END
```

Answer (score -1):

With a third party plugin maybe, but you can still use the `:reg[isters]` command to see the content of all your registers or `:reg 0123456789` for only the numbered registers.

Comment: With all due respect. Without mentioning the actual plugin that does it, this is not an answer - Yeah I know I can run `:reg` but this requires me to visually scan a big paragraph of text - some of which might not even fit on the display. This is hardly fast.

Comment: I have no idea if there's a plugin that does what you want or not but I'm fairly certain there's nothing built-in.